# Pid file and prevent a duplicate instance from running?

Tags: bash, shell, process

I found the following lines at the top of one of our scripts. I understand that it verifies if the PID file is already running it will kill the script to run twice, but I don't really understand what each statement does?

For example, `if kill -0 &>1 > /dev/null $pid; then`. Can someone help me understanding the logic behind this?

```
pidfile=/tmp/backup_meb.pid
if [ -e $pidfile ]; then
    pid=`cat $pidfile`
    if kill -0 &>1 > /dev/null $pid; then
        echo "Already running"
        exit 1
    else
        rm $pidfile
    fi
fi
echo $$ > $pidfile
```

Answer (score 4):

[kill man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/kill):

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

if operates on the return code of the `list` it executes. In this case the return status of `kill`.

Answer (score 3):

> if pidfile exists then
>
> > set pid to the contents of pidfile
> >
> > if pid is a valid process ID
> >
> > > print "Already running" and exit
> >
> > otherwise
> >
> > > delete pidfile
>
> create a new pidfile that contains the ID of the current process

The kill -0 command sends a null signal to the process and the exit code will tell you if the process exists/can be accessed. The &>1 redirects stdout to /dev/null. `$$` is an internal variable in bash that contains the process ID of the script (or shell) itself.